How to avoid 'Changing runtime may terminate your current session'?
I am using google colab for my project. I first used whole environment on gpu but then noticed it is limited so i got solution that i should use and pre-train on cpu then switch to gpu which i tried but always get this

Changing runtime attributes may terminate your current session. Are you sure you want to continue?

If i click yes then whole kernel will restart as a result all files on colab system will be deleted as soon as session is terminated.I can copy those on gdrive but that will make whole training very slow so its better to do on colab subsystem.
How to switch without letting whole session terminate?
If i click yes then whole kernel will restart as a result all files on colab system will be deleted as soon as session is terminated.

How to switch without letting whole session terminate?
There is no way you can transfer data between sessions with different accelerator configurations without using an external storage.
External storage options
For persistent storage of Colab, namely you have three options:
1. Google Drive
Free (for up to 15GB), but has a notoriously slow I/O especially when you read/write a lot of small files. You also have a download quota. As such, Drive is best used as a code storage for model development - it's not the best place to store datasets, which are frequently accessed by the training script.
# Mounting Google Drive
# From the official Colaboratory code snippet
# ----------

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')

with open('/gdrive/My Drive/foo.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('Hello Google Drive!')

The rule of thumb is to minimize I/O to the Google Drive disk. If your Colab VM's disk space allows, you can copy the dataset from Google Drive to somewhere local (outside of /gdrive), and train the model using the local dataset, as mentioned here. This eliminates I/O to Google Drive during the training process.
If your dataset has a lot of small files, archive them as a ZIP file before uploading it to Google Drive. Don't upload small files to (or download them from) Google Drive - it will hurt the performance.
2. Cloud Storage
A pay-as-you-go service which is part of Google Cloud (Google offers a free tier of 5GB/month as of writing). I/O performance is generally better compared to Google Drive, and it has a more sensible quota.
With this option, you're going to mount a Cloud Storage bucket to your Colab instance using Cloud Storage FUSE. Google maintains a benchmark sheet.
When the size of items in the dataset is relatively large (in the order of megabytes - e.g. images, audio files, videos), this is my go-to option at work when storing datasets and artifacts for training models on Google Colab. Still, it has a higher latency than a local filesystem.
# From the official Colaboratory code snippet
# ----------

# Authenticate.
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

# Install Cloud Storage FUSE.
!echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s` main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
!curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
!apt -qq update && apt -qq install gcsfuse

# Mount a Cloud Storage bucket or location, without the gs:// prefix.
mount_path = "my-bucket"  # or a location like "my-bucket/path/to/mount"
local_path = f"/mnt/gs/{mount_path}"

!mkdir -p {local_path}
!gcsfuse --implicit-dirs {mount_path} {local_path}

3. Public data hosting services
Alternatively, you can upload your data to services like HuggingFace and GitHub. Colab offers about 50 GB of storage for the free tier (and about 200GB for Colab Pro users) - if your dataset fits into that space, you can download the data from there.
